# Unexpected slowness in Play framework project with Mongodb and Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.0, morphia

I am building a RSS reader using the Play Framework, play authenticate, and mongodb accessed through Morphia. It's running on a Ubuntu server with a VIA Nano processor U2250 (1.6GHz Capable) and 2ghz ram apparently. Despite every tweak and optimization I could think of, I still observe insane delays in the answering time: from 2seconds to 1 minute to answer a simple HTTP GET request to mark an item as read (I'll talk about this example because it is simple). Note that i am not facing this problem on local tests on my personal machine, just on remote deployment.
Profiling gives me the following distribution of spent time to answer a dozen "mark as read" requests :

```
 org.bson.io.PoolOutputBuffer.pipe() 11%
 org.bson.io.Bits.readFully() 10%
 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.scan() 8%
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select() 7%
 org.bson.io.PoolOutputBuffer.write 5%
 com.google.code.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.getNoArgsConstructor() 5%
```

from which I gathered the I/O with the database was the bottleneck. I have made the references explicit using a custom class Ref<> because Key<> was handling package names fairly poorly. Therefore the aforementioned mark as read request only does 3 db queries : retrieve the item by its ref (id), retrieve the inbox by its ref (id) stored in the session cache, remove the item from the inbox and store it back again. My interactions with the database are encapsulated in a static helper class :

```
public class MorphiaHelper {
    static private Mongo mongo;
    static private Morphia morphia;
    static private Datastore datastore;


    public static void mapModels() {
        morphia.map(...);   
    }

    public static void startup() {
        try {
            mongo = new MongoClient();

            morphia = new Morphia();
            datastore = MorphiaHelper.morphia.createDatastore(MorphiaHelper.mongo, "dbname");

            mapModels();
            updateModelsIfNeeded();

            datastore.ensureIndexes();   
            datastore.ensureCaps();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.error("Database failed to initialize:" + e.getMessage());
        }
        Logger.debug("** mongo and morphia initialization on datastore: " + MorphiaHelper.datastore.getDB()); 
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        mongo.close();
        Logger.debug("** mongo and morphia closed **"); 
    }

    public static <T> Key<T> save(T entity){
        return datastore.save(entity);
    }

    public static <T, V> T get(Ref<V> ref) throws NotFoundException{
        try {
            Class<T> classT = (Class<T>)Class.forName(ref.getClassName());
            return datastore.get(classT, ref.getId());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Reference to morphia not found:" + ref.toString());
        }
    }

...
}
```

and rely on the aforementionned inner static Ref class :

```
    public static interface Referencable{
        Ref getRef();
    }

    public static class Ref<T> implements Serializable, Comparable {
        Map<String, String> id;

        private static String nameToKey(String name){
            return name.replace(".", " ");
        }

        private static String keyToName(String key){
            return key.replace(" ", ".");
        }

        public static <T> Ref<T> fromIdString(Class<T> className, String idString) {
            return new Ref<T>(className, idString);
        }       

        public static Ref<?> fromString(String sourceRefString) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            if (! sourceRefString.contains("=")){
                throw new ClassNotFoundException();
            }
            String[] parseString = sourceRefString.split("=", 2);

            Class<?> className = Class.forName(keyToName(parseString[0]));          
            return fromIdString(className, parseString[1]);         
        }       

        @Deprecated
        private Ref() {}            

        public Ref(Class<T> _className, String _id) {
            id = Collections.singletonMap(nameToKey(_className.getName()), _id);
        }               

        private Entry<String, String> getIdFromMap(){
            return id.entrySet().iterator().next();
        }

        public Object getId(){
            return getIdFromMap().getValue();
        }

        public String toString(){
            return getIdFromMap().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other){
            return (other.getClass().equals(this.getClass()) 
                    && ((Ref)other).getIdFromMap().getKey().equals(this.getIdFromMap().getKey())
                    && ((Ref)other).getIdFromMap().getValue().equals(this.getIdFromMap().getValue()));
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return getIdFromMap().hashCode();
        }

        public String getClassName() {
            return keyToName(getIdFromMap().getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
            return this.toString().compareTo(((Ref) arg0).toString());
        }
    }
```

---

Since I haven't been able to clearly locate the problem, I am also offering you just in case the code of the controller :

```
public static Result read(final String id) throws NotFoundException{
    Item item = MorphiaHelper.get(Ref.fromIdString(Item.class, id));
    Application.getLocalInbox().remove(item);
    return ok();
}
```

This is Application, getting us the inbox :

```
public class Application extends Controller {
 public static Inbox getLocalInbox() throws NotFoundException {
    return Inbox.getInboxOfUser(getLocalUserRef());
 }  

 public static User getLocalUser() throws NotFoundException {
    User user = UserDAO.findUser(PlayAuthenticate.getUser(session()));
    session("UserRef", user.getRef().toString());
    return user;
 }  

 public static Ref<User> getLocalUserRef() throws NotFoundException {
    if (session("UserRef") == null){
         session("UserRef", getLocalUser().getRef().toString());
    } 

    try {
        return (Ref<User>) Ref.fromString(session("UserRef"));
    } catch (Exception e){
        throw new NotFoundException("could not retrieve current user ref");
    }
 }  
}
```

So yeah nothing very interesting here. This is inbox.remove :

```
public void remove(Item item) {     
    // TODO can be optimized if we dont check the existence of tags
    boolean listContainedElement = false;
    for(Ref<Tag> tag : item.getTagsRef()){
        List<Ref<Item>> list = inbox().get(tag);
        if (list != null){
            Ref<Item> key = item.getRef();
            boolean remove = list.remove(key);
            listContainedElement = listContainedElement || remove;

            if (list.size() == 0){
                inbox().remove(tag);
            }
        }
    }

    List<Ref<Item>> list = inbox.get(Tag.getUntagged());
    if (list != null){
        listContainedElement = listContainedElement || list.remove(item.getRef());
    }
    if (listContainedElement) seen(item);
    MorphiaHelper.save(this);   
}
```

where

```
Map<String, List<Ref<Item>>> inbox = new HashMap<String, List<Ref<Item>>>();
Map<Ref<Tag>, List<Ref<Item>>> inbox(){
    return new MorphiaMap(inbox);
}
```

is a way to bypass the fact that morphia cannot handle anything else than Strings as map keys and keep code clean, MorphiaMap being a class storing an attribute "Map innerMap;" and forwarding all the commands with the String to Ref translation.

I'm completely at a loss here so any kind of advice would be much appreciated. I've been tweaking the system for weeks to improve performances but I'm afraid I'm missing the elephant in the room.

Thank you in advance

Best regards

Comment: You might want to narrow this down to specifically what code is causing the bottlenecks before asking for help. It's not as if we can all just drop in your code and start profiling for you.

Comment: I know I'm sorry, I narrowed it as best as I can but the profiling tools aren't much help to locate precisely the problem. My guess is the problem stems from the MorphiaHelper static class but since I'm really unclear about the source I included the other sources in case I'm wrong

Comment: Just pointing out that we are not a code profiling service here. Others may differ but I see question closed in your future if this does not get more specific. Just trying to help you towards an answer.

Comment: well i know that but my problem is precisely that I can't seem to locate the specific part that is causing delays =s I'm sorry. I did rephrase the OP to make it less tedious I hope it helps =s

Comment: I was told to try a reactive mongo driver so I switched to ReactiveMongo (https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo) but did not observe any improvement despite my previous message (I only thought it had improved but the database was too poorly populated for the problem to arise). I am completely at a loss and out of ideas now.

Comment: With the new plugin, the code is somewhat more complex. I'm using the code of Morphia to transform my objects into documents that ReactiveMongo can actually write. Here is the code of DBHelper.java which is basically the layer between my code and the database : http://pastebin.com/Zk2m3Trk
This is an example use case (mark as read) : http://pastebin.com/rUMKkqrr although it's not especially significant I guess (you can see that it calls DBHelper.get and DBHelper.save).